# Creating a tabbed page in MAUI

Tags: xaml, maui

Hello I'm trying to create a TabbedPage in MAUI that has a `Game` button that navigates to my `Game content page`. I want this TabbedPage to function as a dashboard and open after a user has successfully logged in.

Here's my code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="Project.View.DashboardView"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.View">

    <local:GameView Title="Game" />

</TabbedPage>
```

I get 2 errors: `Partial declarations of 'DashboardView' must not specify different base classes` and `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Project.View.DashboardView' to 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Page`

If i change `<TabbedPage>` to `<ContentPage>` it works.

Here's the line of code where the error occurs in my `LoginView.cs`:

```cs
        private void DashboardBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // login check code
            Navigation.PushAsync(new DashboardView());
        }
```

I assume that `Navigation.PushAsync` can only accept `ContentPage`, is there a solution where I can show `TabbedPage` instead after a user logs in ?

Comment: Please show the rest of your code-behind *(.xaml.cs)* file. As the error states, the base class that your page inherits from must be the same in XAML and code-behind (either *TabbedPage*  or *ContentPage*, you cannot mix them). Also make sure to focus on a single problem per question.

Comment: Instead of using  ```Navigation.PushAsync```, you may try ```Application.Current.MainPage = new DashboardView();```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the `Navigation.PushAsync` method to navigate from the Contentpage to the TabbedPage.

It is recommended to use the tabs in the Shell. You can check this [.NET MAUI Shell tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs?view=net-maui-8.0) to create the tabs.